# How can I have an outer ParseQuery match the sort order of an inner ParseQuery?

Tags: android, database, sorting, parse-platform

I have an outer query for `Venue` class, and an Inner query for a `Specialty` class. The inner query is being sorted by `rating` - how can I sort the results of the outer query by that same order?

At the moment the outer query is ignoring any ordering of the inner query, I'm not sure if this is even possible, unfortunately.

What I want to do is be able to rate venues by their individual specialties, and sort the results of a search for bars by, say, their cocktails rating.

`Venue`s have names, addresses etc - as well as an array of `Specialty`s, and the `Specialty` class has a `name`, `venueId`, and `rating`. Hopefully this info helps.

```
ParseQuery<Venue> venueQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Venue");
venueQuery.whereContainedIn("type", Arrays.asList("Pub"));

ParseQuery<ParseObject> specialtyQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Specialty");
specialtyQuery.whereContainedIn("specialty", Arrays.asList("Cocktails", "Whiskey"));
specialtyQuery.orderByDescending("rating");

venueQuery.whereMatchesKeyInQuery("objectId", "venueId", specialtyQuery);

venueQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Venue>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<Venue> venues, ParseException e) {

    });
  }
```

Comment: Do you need to do the sorting in the query itself or would it be acceptable to create a comparator for Venues and use a native Android sort?

Comment: The amount of venues in a given area is going to scale quite high... I would prefer to have the sorting in the query so that I don't have to pull down larger amounts than I would otherwise need to.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, I could limit the inner query to, say, 15, sort that with a comparator, and then when I need more for pagination I could advance the inner query again. This could be a good workaround!

Comment: On most large lists that is pretty much what I do. I pull about the top 20 results, then when the user scrolls to the bottom I will attempt to load more etc. My only concern for you would be would your initial result pull out the top results, if your query isn't sorting properly?